# Problem with Kivy ScrollView TypeError: add_widget() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, kivy

When I start my app this error appears:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "F:\Game\main.py", line 94, in <module>
     kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 301, in load_file
     return self.load_string(data, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 405, in load_string
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 657, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 538, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 655, in _apply_rule
     widget.add_widget(child)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\floatlayout.py", line 140, in add_widget
     return super(FloatLayout, self).add_widget(widget, index, canvas)
   File "C:\Users\marek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\layout.py", line 97, in add_widget
     return super(Layout, self).add_widget(widget, index, canvas)
 TypeError: add_widget() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

My python file:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

import requests, json

URL = "http://127.0.0.1"
#class Login(Screen):
class Data():
    session = None
    tasks = [[1, 'Test Task', 'Das ist eine test Aufgabe', '["Baum", "Haus"]', 'NeonCrafter13']]

Data = Data()

class Login(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    pwd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        username = self.username.text
        pwd = self.pwd.text
        data = {'username':username,'pwd':pwd}
        login = requests.post(URL, data=data)
        try:
            Data.session = login.cookies["session"]
            cookies = {"session": Data.session}
            data = requests.post(URL + "/app_access/getAllTasks", cookies=cookies)
            Data.tasks = json.loads(data.text)
            print(Data.tasks)
            sm.switch_to(screens[1],direction="right")
        except:
            self.username.txt = ""
            self.pwd.text = ""



class TaskGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TaskGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.spacing =  10,10
        self.size_hint =  1.,None
        self.height = self.minimum_height
    data = [[1, 'Test Task', 'Das ist eine test Aufgabe', '["Baum", "Haus"]', 'NeonCrafter13']]
    def create(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name:"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[1])))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Beschreibung"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[2])))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Author"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[4])))

class SelectTask(Screen, ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectTask, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.cols = 1
        self.size_hint=(1, None)
        self.size=(Window.width, Window.height)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        b = 0
        for i in Data.tasks:
            b = b + 1
            c = "T" + str(b)
            globals()[c] = TaskGrid()
            globals()[c].data = i
            globals()[c].create()
            self.add_widget(globals()[c])

    def reload(self):
        b = 0
        for i in Data.tasks:
            b = b + 1
            c = "T" + str(b)
            globals()[c] = TaskGrid()
            globals()[c].data = i
            globals()[c].create()

            self.add_widget(globals()[c])

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()
screens = [Login(name="login"), SelectTask(name="select")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
    def on_pause(self):
      # Here you can save data if needed
      return True
    def on_resume(self):
      # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

My KV File:

```
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

<Label>:
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
<Button>:
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.2

WindowManager:
    Login:
    SelectTask:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    username: username
    pwd: pwd
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            text: "Username:"

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":1}
            id: username
            multiline: False

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.7}
            text: "Password:"

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.7}
            id: pwd
            multiline: False
            password: True

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "bottom":0}
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.submit()

<SelectTask>:
    Button:
        text: "Reload information"
        on_press: root.reload()
```

I want to display a list of all Tasks available on the SelectTask page.

I´m making an App version of a "vocabulary-learn-website."

Before I had this error I don´t had an scroll-view instead I had an GridLayout and it worked all fine.

Please help.

Thank you for your supports in advance.

Comment: I don't think extending both `Screen` and `ScrollView` in the same class `SelectTask` is a good idea. Those two subclasss have different `add_widget()` methods, which I believe is causing the error message. I think a better approach would be to just add a `ScrollView` to the `SelectTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John Anderson with your help I could fix the problem.

For anyone intressted:

**Python File:**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window

import requests, json

URL = "http://192.168.178.60"
#class Login(Screen):
class Data():
    session = None
    tasks = [[1, 'Test Task', 'Das ist eine test Aufgabe', '["Baum", "Haus"]', 'NeonCrafter13']]

Data = Data()

class Login(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    pwd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        username = self.username.text
        pwd = self.pwd.text
        data = {'username':username,'pwd':pwd}
        login = requests.post(URL, data=data)
        try:
            Data.session = login.cookies["session"]
            cookies = {"session": Data.session}
            data = requests.post(URL + "/app_access/getAllTasks", cookies=cookies)
            Data.tasks = json.loads(data.text)
            print(Data.tasks)
            sm.switch_to(screens[1],direction="right")
        except:
            self.username.txt = ""
            self.pwd.text = ""



class TaskGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TaskGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
    data = [[1, 'Test Task', 'Das ist eine test Aufgabe', '["Baum", "Haus"]', 'NeonCrafter13']]
    def create(self):
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name:"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[1])))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Beschreibung"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[2])))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Author"))
        self.add_widget(Label(text=str(self.data[4])))

class SelectTaskScrollView(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectTaskScrollView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(1, None)
        self.size=(Window.width, Window.height)
        self.do_scroll_x = False
        b = 0
        self.inside = GridLayout()
        self.inside.cols = 1
        btn = Button(text="Reload")
        btn.bind(on_press=self.reload)
        self.inside.add_widget(btn)
        for i in Data.tasks:
            b = b + 1
            c = "T" + str(b)
            globals()[c] = TaskGrid()
            globals()[c].data = i
            globals()[c].create()
            self.inside.add_widget(globals()[c])
        self.add_widget(self.inside)

    def reload(self, instance):
        b = 0
        for i in Data.tasks:
            b = b + 1
            c = "T" + str(b)
            globals()[c] = TaskGrid()
            globals()[c].data = i
            globals()[c].create()

            self.inside.add_widget(globals()[c])

class SelectTask(Screen):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(SelectTask, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(SelectTaskScrollView())



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")
sm = WindowManager()
screens = [Login(name="login"), SelectTask(name="select")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
    def on_pause(self):
      # Here you can save data if needed
      return True
    def on_resume(self):
      # Here you can check if any data needs replacing (usually nothing)
      pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**KV File:**

```
<TextInput>:
    size_hint: 0.5, 0.1

<Label>:
    size_hint: 0.25, 0.1
<Button>:
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.2

WindowManager:
    Login:
    SelectTask:

<Login>:
    name: "login"
    username: username
    pwd: pwd
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":1}
            text: "Username:"

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":1}
            id: username
            multiline: False

        Label:
            pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.7}
            text: "Password:"

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.4, "top":0.7}
            id: pwd
            multiline: False
            password: True

        Button:
            pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "bottom":0}
            text: "Submit"
            on_press: root.submit()
```